# Termux proot-distro install fedora error

Tags: fedora, system-installation, termux

When I use `proot-distro`, it shows me this error:

```bash
~ $ proot-distro install fedora
[*] Installing Fedora...
[*] Creating directory '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/var/lib/proot-distro/installed-rootfs/fedora'...
[*] Creating directory '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/var/lib/proot-distro/installed-rootfs/fedora/.l2s'...
[!] The distribution download URL is not defined for CPU architecture 'arm'.
[!] Exiting due to failure.
```

I searched about this on the web but didn't find anything useful. I also checked if it works for other distributions like Debian by running `proot-distro install debian`. I didn't let the installation finish; when I saw it had passed the URL error, I cancelled it using CTRL+C.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, there is no URL included in `proot-distro` for the `arm` architecture. `arm` is 32 bit, and there's no 32 bit Fedora any more.

There **[is](https://github.com/termux/proot-distro/blob/855f1e6fd4f645666843c16451a14c5270d449e8/distro-plugins/fedora.sh#L7-L10)** however one for aarch64, i.e., for the modern 64 bit ARM processors. So if this is a problem on a modern ARM platform where you could choose between a 32 bit OS and a 64 bit OS (like on modern Raspberry Pi), then go back and choose again.

There is, however, a 32 bit `arm` version of debian, as noted in `proot-distro`'s [recipe](https://github.com/termux/proot-distro/blob/855f1e6fd4f645666843c16451a14c5270d449e8/distro-plugins/debian.sh#L9), which is why the debian setup works.